# How to do the bottom alignment of two child DIVs nested inside the parent DIV?

Tags: css

The parent `DIV` nests 2 child `DIV:box2 box3`, which are stacked vertically,
`box2` bottom is aligned with `box3` top
`box3` bottom is aligned with `box1` bottom

How should CSS be written?

Snippet:

```css
.box1 {
  width: 315px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.box2 {
  width: 315px;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.box3 {
  width: 315px;
  height: 38px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `flex-end` of `flex` layout.

```css
.box1 {
        width: 315px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: #FFF;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-end;
}
```